# Incrementally update aggregates in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have created a cube based on a data frame which contains several columns and an aggregated sum.

```
val cubeData = initialData 
    .toDF("age", "country", "monthy_salary", "num_of_cars")
    .cube("age", "country", "monthy_salary", "num_of_cars") 
    .agg( sum("num_of_cars") as "sum_num_of_cars" )
```

As new records come in I would like to update the cube (DF) and the aggregation values.

What would be most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Try using updateStateByKey.

Comment: Is this feasible even for potentially updating an aggregated value in every row (millions) of a DF for every incoming record?